# Звідки пішло "пантелик"?

Tags: етимологія

Цікавить не значення фразеологізму "збити з пантелику" (бо воно зрозуміле), а його походження. Словникова стаття на СУМ-11 для [*пантелик*](http://sum.in.ua/s/pantelyk) лише переадресовує на зворот.

Словник Даля не дуже допомагає:

> ПАНТАЛЫК, пантелик, толк, смысл, порядок. В голове панталыку нет. Сбить кого, либо сбиться с панталыку, с толку, говорить и делать вздор.

Що це могло бути? Інтуітивно здається, що мав би бути якийсь фізичний контекст.

Answer (score 14):

Це слово "не зовсім ясне" навіть для етимологічного словника:

> Разом з польським *pętlik* (*pętlika*), словацьким *pántlik* і
>   угорським *pantlika* традиційно виводять від австрійсько-баварського
>   *раntl* - петля, зав'язка, стрічка. Звідси й гуцульське *пантлика*.

Є навіть [така версія](https://www.ar25.org/article/shcho-take-pantelyk.html), але виглядає підозріло.

Як на мене, тут можливі 2 варіанти:

1. Стрічка у значенні шляху (когось збивають з правильного шляху до 
   вирішення проблеми);
2. Первинне значення петлі, вузла (хтось от-от має розплутати вузол, але йому заважають).

Хоча жодна з них не витримує ніякої конкуренції, тож не буду нічого стверджувати.

Answer (score 11):

Взято [звідси](http://mech.math.msu.su/~apentus/znaete/slova/p.htm):

> `Панталик` - спотворене `Пантелик`, гора в Аттиці зі сталактитовою
>   печерою і гротами, в яких було легко заблукати.

В українській мові слово `пантелик` набуло сенсу `ход логічних міркувань`, з якого можна `збити`, але жодним чином не можна `з'їхати` (для цього є `ҐЛУЗД`).

Answer (score 6):

Людмила Даниленко у розвідці "[Український пантелик та його рецепція у слов’янських мовах (до походження фразеологізму збити з пантелику)](https://journals.pan.pl/Content/116793/PDF/2020-02-SOR-09-Danilenko.pdf)" припускає, що "пантелик" міг бути вигаданий Котляревським при написанні "Енеїди":

> ...
>
> До  третього  видання  1809  р.  на  базі  першого  словника  1798  року письменник  склав  новий,  значно  розширений  українсько-російський  словник, що  мав  свою  пагінацію,  під  назвою "Словарь малороссийских слов, содержащихся в Энеиде и многих иных в Малороссии употребительных, исправленный, умноженный и дополненный словами для четвертой части". Порівняння словників із трьох прижиттєвих видань "Енеїди" І. Котляревського показало, що слово *пантелик*, записане  у  формі *панталикъ*, тлумачилося  як *глузд*:  «панталикъ, глуздъ»
>
> ...
>
> В "Енеїді" Котляревського богиня  Юнона просить бога вітрів Еола потопити Енеєві кораблі, а тому рядок *Ізбий Енея з пантелику* прочитується як ʻзбий з дороги, з <морської> путіʼ
>
> ...
>
> Слово *пантелик* можна вважати спорідненим з дінд. *pánthāh* «стежка, дорога, путь», гр. *pátos* ʻстежкаʼ, *póntos* ʻмореʼ та утвореним додаванням тюркського суфікса -lyk-,  поширеного  у  складі  іменників  зі  значенням  “місце”,  пор.  тат. *tašlyk* “кам'янисте місце”, *Кагарлик* “місто в Київській області”. У такому разі слово *пантелик* первісно могло  означати “морська  путь”, де суфікс  -лик- у процесі засвоєння увійшов до складу кореня.
>
> ...
>
> *Пантелик* – явно бурлескний  словесний  витвір,  перекручене  звукове  оформлення  чи  імітація слова *толк*. І. Котляревський  скористався  типовим  стилістичним  прийомом, властивим  бурлескній  манері  викладу,  заради  гумору  й  комізму.  Можливо, письменникові це знадобилося для рими: *сватоньку-старику* – *з пантелику*, як у строфі *филозопи* – *крутопопи*.

Comment: Ах, точно. Якраз було в [ТПГ-і.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2tDqhJHwu4g)

Answer (score -1):

То, виглядає, таки й справді від Пантелеймона - святого, покровителя воїнів. А Пантелик - форма того імені. Отже, "збити з пантелику" - позбавити його покровительства.

І ні, то не польське, не німецьке і не ще чиєсь. Та ви лише погляньте на тих репінських козарлюг: ну хто ще міг таке придумати?!

Comment: Ласкаво просимо до сайту Ukrainian Language.SE! Наші критерії якості дещо відрізняються від того, що можна побачити на мовних форумах і блоґах. Необґрунтовані відповіді базуються лише на думці їхнього автора і тому викликають хвилю диспутів і заперечень. А якісні відповіді ґрунтуються на якісних джерелах: словниках, поважних сайтах тощо. Будь ласка, перегляньте сторінки [tour], [answer] а також [«Якими мають бути гарні відповіді»](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/). Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, зробивши її більш аргументованою. Для цього натисніть [edit].